# Change opacity for pre-defined color?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nscolor

What would be the best (as in: *most concise*) way for **setting just the alpha component** of a **predefined** color?

Say I'd like to use something like `+ (NSColor *)brownColor` but with 50% opacity -
I couldn't find an appropriate constructor like `..fromNSColor:` that would allow us to change the alpha component and with `NSColor` being immutable is there any other convenience method we can use to alter the alpha component whilst keeping r/g/b components the same?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/applicationkit/classes/NSColor_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSColor/colorWithAlphaComponent:) method:

```
[[NSColor brownColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.5];
```

It returns a new color with the same RGB as the receiver but with a new alpha.

Comment: Man, I must go blind :-)

Comment: @ATV: Apple's documentation isn't exactly the easiest to search.

Answer (score 4):

There is indeed a method for NSColor doing that:

```
[[NSColor brownColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.1];
```

That would give you brown with 10% opacity.